# MPI Scatter losing values from the final partition

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I have an array of numbers that I need to scatter to each node in an MPI program. The setup is that I have an array of numbers from 1 to 100 with all the even numbers except the number 2 removed. Due to the way I removed the even numbers, the number 2 is the last element in the array.

So my array contains 51 odd numbers, 3, 5, 7, ... 99, 2. My problem is that the final partition after a scatter does not contain the last three numbers in the array - 97, 99 and 2.

```
int *oddsOnly  = //array as setup above, 3,5,7,...99,2
int chunkSize = (oddsFound / worldSize);
int *localPartition = new int[chunkSize];

// Send everyone the chunk size
MPI_Bcast(&chunkSize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Scatter(oddsOnly, chunkSize, MPI_INT, localPartition, chunkSize, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I understand the issue is that the number of ranks and the array size don't divide evenly, I've tried

```
chunkSize = ceil(oddsFound / worldSize);
```

And

```
chunkSize = (oddsFound / worldSize) + 1;
```

But this then gives me duplicates in the split.

As it stands I get

```
0 scatter is 1  3   5   7   9   11  13  15  17  19  21  23

1 scatter is 25 27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  

2 scatter is 49 51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71

3 scatter is 73 75  77  79  81  83  85  87  89  91  93  95
```

Is it possible to do what I'm attemptimg tidily? I had a look at scatterV but I'm not sure its what I need. I should add I don't *have* to scatter, so maybe there is a better MPI way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `MPI_Scatter` and add padding to the array so that its size is evenly divisible among processes. However, whenever a process has to manipulate that array it needs to ignore the padding part.

Another approach is to use [MPI_ScatterV](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html), and "manually" divide the blocks among the processes.

An example of such approach:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
    int world_rank; 
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);

    int size = 50;
    int *numbers= NULL;
    if(world_rank == 0){
      numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         numbers[i] = (2*i + 1); 
    }
    // The Important Part
    int sendcounts [world_size];
    int displs [world_size]; 
    int res = size % world_size;
    int size_per_process = size / world_size;
    int increment = 0;
    for(int processID = 0; processID < world_size; processID++){
       displs[processID] = increment;
       sendcounts[processID] = (processID + 1 <= res) ? size_per_process + 1 : size_per_process;
       increment += sendcounts[processID];
    }
    int process_size = sendcounts[world_rank];
    int local_numbers[process_size];
    MPI_Scatterv(numbers, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, local_numbers, process_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
    if(world_rank == world_size - 1){
       for(int i = 0; i < size_per_process; i++)
      printf("%d ", local_numbers[i]); 
       printf("\n"); 
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

It is a bit convoluted, but the good news is that it is always the same for this type of distribution.

**Explanation of the code:**

First we need to understand the parameters of the [MPI_Scatterv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html):

> **MPI_Scatterv**
>
> Scatters a buffer in parts to all processes in a communicator
>
> ```
> int MPI_Scatterv(const void *sendbuf, const int *sendcounts, const int *displs, MPI_Datatype sendtype, void *recvbuf, int recvcount,
>           MPI_Datatype recvtype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
> ```

**Input Parameters**

> **sendbuf** address of send buffer (choice, significant only at root) 
> **sendcounts** integer array (of length group size) specifying the number of elements to send to each processor 
> **displs** integer array (of length group size). Entry i specifies the displacement (relative to sendbuf from which to take the outgoing data to process i 
> **sendtype** data type of send buffer elements (handle) 
> **recvcount** number of elements in receive buffer (integer)   
> **recvtype** data type of receive buffer elements (handle)  
> **root** rank of sending process (integer) 
> **comm** communicator (handle)

First, we create the array with the number of elements that each process will send:

```
int sendcounts [world_size];
```

then we create the array with the displacements:

```
int displs [world_size];
```

then we calculate the number of extra iterations:

```
int res = size % world_size;
```

then we calculate the number of iterations that each process are guarantee to have:

```
int size_per_process = size / world_size;
```

Finally, we calculate the size and the displacement of each process:

```
int increment = 0;
for(int processID = 0; processID < world_size; processID++){
   displs[processID] = increment;
   sendcounts[processID] = (processID + 1 <= res) ? size_per_process + 1 : size_per_process;
   increment += sendcounts[processID];
}
```

the line:

```
   sendcounts[processID] = (processID + 1 <= res) ? size_per_process + 1 : size_per_process;
```

means that we will assign the extra iterations from left to right (*i.e.,* from process rank 0 to rank total of processes - 1).